# Adding and subtracting function not working on cloned div's - javascript

Tags: jquery

So I have a form, where users can add or subtract time in minutes and they can also clone that div and add more values, but my problem is that I can't seem to get the function work on cloned div's. The function only adds or subtracts from the first div.

Here's jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W7w58/2/

Clicking on the + or - starts the function.

Here's the code, but I guess it is easier to understand the problem when trying out the jsFiddle:

HTML:

```
<button id="clone-btn">Clone</button>
<div id="clone-div">
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-subtract">-</a>
   <a href="#" class="btn"><input type="text" class="input-field" id="input-field" name="input-field" value="0:00"></a>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-add">+</a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
/* for cloning */
$("#clone-btn").click(function() {
    $('#clone-div').clone(true).insertAfter('#clone-div');
    return false;
});


/* for the function */
var $input = $('.input-field');
$input.data('minutes', parseTimeString($input.val()));

function parseTimeString(str) {
    var time = str.split(":");
    return (parseInt(time[0])*60) + parseInt(time[1]);
}

$('.btn-add').on('click', function() {
    changeTime(1);
});

$('.btn-subtract').on('click', function() {
    changeTime(-1);
});
function changeTime(mins) {
    var currentTime = parseInt($input.data('minutes')),
    newTime = currentTime + mins,
    minutes = (newTime % 60).toString(),
    hours = (Math.floor(newTime / 60)).toString();
    if (minutes.length === 0) {
        minutes = "00";
    } else if (minutes.length === 1) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    $input.data('minutes', newTime).val(hours + ":" + minutes);
}
```

I would appreciate all the help you can give me :).

Comment: i found your problems i am working on exact solution for you

Comment: almost got complete working solution and explanation for u

Comment: hey MyT I have working solution where it increments each text box individually but Im not sure what u are trying to do with the "time" can u come to chat for a second?  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22401/inc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems with your original code were:

1. usage of data attribute where unnecessary
2. usage of duplicate ids
3. not dealing with new copies of your textbox but instead modifying the original textbox.
4. **Hidden issue:** zero padding
   in your code during calculation of the time was causing problems, causing the time only to 
   work up to 0:08 and then going back to 0:00 when using individual textboxes instead of just one textbox. It is fixed and works correctly in my solution.

Below is a working solution where the time increment and decrement works properly for clones as well and they work individually as you want them to.

This code also includes what you said you wanted in our chat - not to go below 0:00 when clicking the "minus" button (in example it generates an alert). Hope it helps!

Also jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vwxfC/4/

JS CODE:

```
$("#clone-btn").click(function () {
    var last = $('.cdiv').eq(-1);
    last.clone(true).insertAfter(last);
    return false;
});

function parseTimeString(str) {
    var time = str.split(":");
    if (time[1][0] === "0") {
        time[1] = time[1].substr(1, time[1].length);
    }

    return (parseInt(time[0]) * 60) + parseInt(time[1]);
}

$('.btn-add').on('click', function () {
    changeTime(1, this);
});

$('.btn-subtract').on('click', function () {
    changeTime(-1, this);
});
function changeTime(mins, el) {
    var inp = $(el).siblings('.btninp').eq(0).children('.input-field').eq(0);

    if (inp.val() == "0:00" && mins == "-1") {

        alert("time cannot be less than 0!");
    } else {

        var ps = parseTimeString(inp.val());

        var currentTime = parseInt(ps),
        newTime = currentTime + mins,
        minutes = (newTime % 60).toString(),
        hours = (Math.floor(newTime / 60)).toString();
        if (minutes.length < 2) {
            minutes = "0" + minutes;
        }

        inp.val(hours + ":" + minutes);
    }

}
```

HTML CODE:

```
<button id="clone-btn">Clone</button>
<div class = "cdiv">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-subtract">-</a>
  <a href="#" class="btninp"><input type="text" class="input-field" value="0:00"> </input></a>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-add">+</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: btw if for some reason you want each cloned textbox to start at 0:00 instead of the value that was in the last textbox it was cloned from, I added this line of code in the clone btn function after line 3, which is after creation of the clone, the new line of code is: $('.input-field').eq(-1).val("0:00") in order to reset the most recently cloned input box to 0:00 after it has been created - and the jsfiddle for that is here:  http://jsfiddle.net/vwxfC/6/ -- hope all of this helps and happy coding!

Comment: I can't thank you enough, worked like a charm. I really appreciate it. Thank you, thank you, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few problems here:

1. Your `<div>` tag has an `id` attribute, which is meant to be unique. Cloning it will create two elements with the same `id`, which will cause problems for you. Use a `class` attribute instead.
2. Your event handlers aren't accounting for the dynamically generated elements. To do that, you use the event delegation syntax of `.on()`:

   ```
   $('#closest_static_parent').on('click', '.btn-add', function() {
   ```
3. `$input` is hard-coded. Instead of `$input`, find your `<input>` element relative to the `<a>` by using:

   ```
   $(this).closest('input');
   ```